# How to run the SQL code and loop/display the results on the same aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to create a homepage for my asp .net project, which should display all the products available from the database. The code below is my aspx code, and I've labelled the code I'm trying to loop and display all the results from the database with --> and <--.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Try.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<section class="py-5">      
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
                  
                    <div class="col mb-5">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                       -->  <!-- Product image-->
                            <img class="card-img-top" width="205.99px" height="205.99px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%= @Convert.ToBase64String(*product image*) %>" alt="..." />
                            <!-- Product details-->
                            <div class="card-body p-4">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    
                                    <!-- Product name-->
                                    <h5 class="fw-bolder">*product name*</h5>
                                    <!-- Product price-->
                                    *product price*<br/>
                                    *product description*
                                </div>
                            </div> <--
                            
                            <!-- Product actions-->
                            <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="productDetails.aspx">Details</a></div><br />
                            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="home.aspx">Add to cart</a></div> 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code below are the code which I currently left at the aspx.cs page to run the SQL and retrieve the result. I wish to put it somewhere within the aspx page with <% %> but there are errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Try
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConfigConString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            con.Open();

            string strHome = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";
            SqlCommand cmdHome = new SqlCommand(strHome, con);

            SqlDataReader dtrHome = cmdHome.ExecuteReader();

            while (dtrHome.Read())
            {
                //display the result from database on the aspx page
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @Crowcoder I mean I tried to copy the whole code (starting from using System) into the aspx page inside a <% %> and it didn't worked, and I guess there should be an easier and smarter way to do this...

Comment: I don't know why you are using webforms for a new project in 2022, but if so you might as well use it as intended. I suggest you [data bind a repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/x4s0xktt(v=vs.100)) to generate the content

Comment: WebForms is ancient, you should consider using more modern frameworks. Also, your connection, command and reader objects need `using`

Comment: @Crowcoder This is actually an assignment so I have no choice, I will try your solution and thanks.

Comment: Actually, webforms is a great way to get into asp.net. It has about 1/10th the learning curve of MVC. And the BEST new features announced in vs2022 are for web forms. Read this:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: A GREAT example of why Webforms is a great way to get into asp.net? Notice how you have people suggesting to use MVC, but THEN THEY don't offer a simple working example? Why? (because MVC is too much work for a simple post on SO!!!). Once you get up to speed on WebForm, then by all means consider jumping over to MVC, but for getting started? If we chase away too many people from adopting and trying out asp.net? Then the door is slammed on those entering the asp.net eco-system. Right now, FEW are entering and adopting asp.net, and the reason is the learning curve is too steep now.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I disagree. MVC is not difficult to learn. And when you learn it you are learning how HTTP works which is transferable knowledge to many other frameworks. WebForms tries to hide HTTP which leaves users ignorant of how browsers and servers work which is a necessary skill these days.

Comment: Easy learn that additional information, and you WILL have to. The simple matter and proof of what I say here? How come no MVC answers here? Look at my answer - it took less time then to write the post. If MVC was so easy, then we should see some people pile in with WORKING examples and code, yet we see no takers! Why is that? (answer: it takes too much effort and time for a simple SO post + answer to do that kind of work). As noted, with a lower learning curve, you can enter the asp.net eco-system. I use jQuery, ajax and all that stuff with ease now - but learning at same time is too much

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal there are no MVC answers here because the question is about WebForms. I'm not saying WebForms is all bad. I don't advocate re-writing WebForms apps just because it is old. It is just a disservice to students when WebForms is taught instead of something more relevant in the work force.

Comment: Sure, but the issue is developer costs vs money spent. Because MVC forces you to learn all those things? Then as a developer you gain zero more advantages in the marketplace over some developer who adopts the LAMP stack or whatever.  MVC does not make you more productive, but in fact LESS so. That just means all MVC developers are now on par with any other developer using any other platform (they don't get any more done for a given amounts of efforts). You can see even Microsoft has realized this huge mistake. Look at best new features in vs2022 (link above) - they ARE for webform developers!

Comment: I find more work in webforms, since many sites were built as such in last 15+ years. Such companies are NOT spending money at all on newer frameworks unless they have to. You can't just keep increasing the cost of software development, since then that lowers the value of that developer. If the cost of butter goes up, then consumers will buy more margarine.  The simple matter? The WHOLE industry will go back and is moving towards a GUI + drag + drop development approach. Once that occurs, little of these stuff behind will matter. And the industry WAS that way at one time - including webforms

Comment: Webforms is without question legacy software. However, it ALSO gets people into the asp.net eco system. Right now, few are entering and adopting asp.net, since you have to spend as much time as using any old other platform. And without MVC giving you advantages over the other platforms available? Then fewer and fewer people are entering the asp.net system, since they just gave up any advantages of adopting that platform. So, after one gets into asp.net? Then sure, by all means start to learn blazer and MVC. But we need to draw people into asp.net, and MVC does not at all allow this with ease.

Comment: Another great example? Take a simple grid, add a edit button. Super simple in web forms. I looked, and the time to cook this SIMPLE web form up in MVC is more then double the time. Here is a simple working example - should only take you about a hour - you show me yours, and I'll show you mine. Here is my example: (simple CRUD edit). http://www.kallal.ca/WebSite11/WebForm2

Comment: Now, having stated all the above? You are still giving good advice - WebForms is legacy, older, and that is 100% fine to point out, and should be pointed out!! - but given that the best new features in vs2022 is for web forms? It certainly not dead, and as I explained, we need to get and keep and have people move into the asp.net eco system. If we don't, then asp.net will fail to attract new developers, and that makes all asp..net developers less valuable in the market place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the most common way to "display" repeating data?

Is to use one of the built in controls that displays repeating data. Then you can "feed" the control the data source, and asp.net does the work for you!

So, say I drop in a GridView (often a great choice).

So, now our markup is this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="70%">

        </asp:GridView>
```

And our code on page load is now this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();

    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                @"SELECT ID, Fighter, Engine, Thrust, Description FROM Fighters";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And our results are now this:

[image]

So, in effect we can layout "one thing", and then have it repeated.

Now, my Fighters table has a column that links to picture.

So, I can use the wizard to create the GV, and then delete the sql data source on the page, and say with this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdView" runat="server" Width="150px"
                        ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                        OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And now I get this:

[image]

But, maybe I don't want a grid, but a card like view?

Ok, then we can use a "repeater".

Again, the idea is we layout ONE thing, and then feed it data, and it "repeats" for us.

So, lets now use  repeater.

Inside the repeater, we create "one" thing we want to display.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>                   
        <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:320px;height:450px;float:left;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <div style="text-align:center;padding:2px 10px 2px 10px">
                <h3><%# Eval("Fighter") %></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="170" />
                <h4>Engine</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' />
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code to load - idential (just send that rstData (our table) to the repeater.

We now get this:

[image]

And because each "repeated" thing is a simple div (floated left),

Then if I re-size my browser, then I see this (for a big wide screen browser and monitor).

[image]

As you can see, you get a LOT of nice repeating data, and for VERY little efforts on your part.

Since you wanting to display products? Then use a GridView, or often better a ListView. You can even let the wizard generate that grid or listview for you. Then you can clean it up a bit, or leave as is.

## Edit#2: How to get the row in question with a button click?

Ok, the next logical issue and question? We VERY much will have a button click for each of the rows of data.

With a GridView, it is far better, since the gridview has what we call "datakeys". This allows a easy row click, and code behind can then get with great ease the row you just clicked on. And VERY nice is gridview/listview (and a few more data repeating controls has this data keys option. This option is VERY important, since then we NEVER have to show, expose or even have the database PK value show in the browser side markup and code. Even if we "hide" the field and value in the browser - it STILL not a great idea to EVER expose, or EVEN allow database key id's in the browser side).

However, unfortatnly, the "repeater" is NOT one of those controls that has the datakeys option!!!

So, there are two solutions. One is to use somthing other then the repeater.

but, it not the end of the world, and lets just go with a plane jane button, and include with that button the current database row pk id. (as noted, not a huge deal, but my coding standards do not have nor expose or use or allow users to see the database pk in the browser side markup. It really comes down to how high secuirty you want and need here. So, we can just include the database pk id here, and it not the end of the world.

As noted, if using gridview or listview (and a few others), then data keys and the PK row ID can be had with great ease - no special markup or expose of the PK row id is required. But, lets just use the repeater.

So, in our above card like view (and if you are NOT using a card like view, but repeating rows of data, then I do suggest listview, or datalistview, since datlist view works VERY much like the repeater - but has more features. In fact the big problem here is so many controls to choose from!!!  (I tend to learn just a few of them, and use that control. But, for the most part all of these data repating type of controls work VERY much the same. So, once you learn one, then you can use that knowledge with all of them.

So, lets drop in a plain jane button into the repeater. Say at the top and to the right (I choosing top, since if I put button on the bottom, then the location of the button will vary/change, and that's not great for the user as they can "learn" what spot to click on over and over - easy for user).

So, we drop in a plane jane button, add the click event, and we have this:

```
                <asp:Button ID="cmdMyView" runat="server" Text="View" 
                    CssClass="btn-info" style="float:right"
                    OnClick="cmdMyView_Click"
                    CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                    />
                <br />
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

And our button code can be this:

```
    protected void cmdMyView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        int MyRowIndex = rRow.ItemIndex;
        int MyPK = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + MyRowIndex);
        Debug.Print("Pk data base = " + MyPK);

        // get say the engine from the row click
        Label lblEngine = (Label)rRow.FindControl("EngineLabel2");
        Debug.Print("engine = " + lblEngine.Text);            
    }
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hey man now I have another problem, by display all the products through repeater, I have an onclick button for each of the product that allows the user to add it to their cart, how can I assign different id and pass it to the onclick function for each of the product? I've attempted to use hidden field and a foreach loop to go through repeater items, but only the biggest id will be selected...

Comment: See my edit - you don't need a loop. The button click will send the row information. But, since you have "repeating" controls, then you have to use findcontrol to get values from that given row.

Comment: OMG thank you once again man for such clear explaination, all of the other posts I've referred got me very confused :DD